# ui-router issue, cant load child view from tab

Tags: ionic-framework

Im trying to get a single nested view to load within a tab and it seems that anything I try it will not load the template. Im trying to pass a param from my main tab view to load a child view and display it. The page never loads but i see that the url has changed with my selected value from the list. I have followed the example from ionic tabs starter exactly, but this darn thing will not show the child page.

Here is my app.js with the appropriate code minus everything else.

> ```
> // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
> .state('options', {
>   url: "/options",
>   abstract: true,
>   templateUrl: "templates/options-tabs.html"
> })
>
>
> // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
>
> .state('options.create', {
>   url: '/create',
>   views: {
>     'options-create': {
>       templateUrl: 'templates/options-create.html',
>       controller: 'CreateCtrl'
>     }
>   }
> })
>
> .state('options.confirm', {
>   url: '/confirm/:id',
>   views: {
>     'options-confirm': {
>       templateUrl: 'templates/options-confirm.html',
>       controller: 'ConfirmCtrl'
>     }
>   }
> })
>
> .state('options.local', {
>   url: '/local',
>   views: {
>     'options-local': {
>       templateUrl: 'templates/options-local.html',
>       controller: 'LocalAuditCtrl'
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```

My Controller

> .controller('CreateCtrl', function($scope,$location,$state,rest) {
>       rest.getBases().success(function(data){
>         $scope.bases = data;
>       });
>
> ```
> $scope.test = function(account){
>   console.log(account);
>   $state.go('options.confirm', {id:account});
> }
> ```
>
> })

My Main Tab View

```
<ion-view title="Create">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="base in bases" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="test(base.account)">
        {{base.name}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Details View

```
<ion-view title="{{id}}">
  <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

At this point Im completely confused on how this can be wrong following the example from Ionic but Im sure there is something Im missing =( Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and after 3 hours of debugging I found out that your top state (the abstract one) must be `<ion-nav-view/>`.

Ionic's doc doesn't mention it at all!

Try to include this in the index.html file.

Comment: Actually it does and in multiple places.